# JQuery and Ajax: show/hide div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, hide, show

I have this [example](http://www.vuotoaperdere.org/jqueryajax.htm).

When I click, a dynamic content load via Ajax. In the loaded page there is a link, that could close the div. It works, but when the div is closed (with hide()), the click on link don't reopen loaded page.

Why? How can I create a button, that show/hide a div loaded with Ajax?

**Calling page :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAjax(divdett,pageload) {
$(function(){$(divdett).load(pageload);});}
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>click</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:getAjax('#siteloader','jquery_divajax.htm');">click</a>
<div id="siteloader"></div>
</body>
```

**Included page :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delAjax(divdett) {
$(divdett).hide();
}
</script>
OK!
<a id="#chiudi" href="#" onclick="delAjax('#siteloader');">chiudi</a>
```

Comment: I answered but please, next time, include relevant parts of the code in your question, especially when it's so short.

Comment: I edited your question to include the code.

Answer (score 1):

In your "close" button, you call `hide()`.

Change your `getAjax` function to this :

```
function getAjax(divdett,pageload) {
$(function(){$(divdett).load(pageload).show();});}
```

I just added `.show()` to ensure the div is visible even if it has been made hidden before.

Note that I respected the original construct but this is much too complex : no need to call `$(function` when you can simply do

```
function getAjax(divdett,pageload) {
$(divdett).load(pageload).show();}
```

If you want to have only one button, you may remove the one of the second file and change the getAjax function to

```
function getAjax(divdett,pageload) {
     var div = $(divdett);
     if (div.is(':visible')) div.hide();
     else div.load(pageload).show();
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank's a lot. It work's fine. One question. But if i want to use only one button for load page and hide div? What can i do this?

Comment: Yes that can be done by checking visibility of the div
**if($('#siteloader').is(':visible'))** //hide div
**else** //load site

Comment: I edited with a one button solution (probably what Sahil had in mind).

Comment: The function is OK but it have only one problem. The first time you click the button then div is set to hide, but it is already hide. I have modified the button to set it to hide the first time.
<img src="img/update.png" onclick="javascript:getAjax('#siteloader','jquery_divajax.asp');" onload="$('#siteloader').hide()">


One more question.

But if i use JQuery tools like TipTip or DatePicker, into a loaded page "jquery_divajax.htm" their works right? Or i need to recall funtions that set them?

Comment: There is no problem with hiding a div that is yet hidden, no need to test. For the inclusion of other tools, hard to tell with so few details (and in comments). I'd suggest you to test and ask a question if there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't work because HTML DOM already loaded. For dynamic binding you need to use function `.bind()` or `.live()` ([Documentation for bind()](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)).

For example:

```
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", function() {
  $( this ).hide(); // or show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would using an unobtrusive approach, separating the html from the javascript (jQuery) code, and like @dystroy very well pointed out, just show the div before the ajax request is made to make sure it's visible:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>click</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#clickme').on('click', function(event) {
                $('#siteloader').show().load('jquery_divajax.htm');
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            $('#siteloader').on('click', '#chiudi', function(event) {
                $('#siteloader').hide();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="clickme" href="">click</a>
    <div id="siteloader"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

well my answer may help you...
giving you the scenario...

you can use if else in response of ajax request

```
$.ajax(
            {
                url:"ChkLogin.php",
                type:"POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {usernm: unm, passwrd: pass },
                success:function(myoutput)
                {                   
                    $(":hidden").val(myoutput.srno);
                    if(myoutput.flag=="1")
                    {                                       
                        window.location="chat.php";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#msg").html("Invalid Login");
                    }
                }

            });
```

> is response in 1 then do this
>   else
>   do this

like....

```
if(myoutput.flag=="1")
                    {                                       
                        $("#div").hide(4000);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#div").show(4000);
                    }
```

> here 4000 are ms(milliseconds) takes to hide or show the DIV]
>   Hope this will help you